# How to resolve the duplicated inserted rows when I send multiple requests in the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this code and I send multiple requests. After I check the database, duplicate rows have been created in the table.

How to solve this problem?

```
public async Task<IDataResult<StartWorkResponseMobileDto>> SendStartWork(StartWorkSendMobileDto startWorkSendMobileDto)
{
    try
    {
        var checkStartWork = await startWorkDal.Get(x => x.CreatedBy==requestUserUtil.GetCurrentUserId() && x.CreatedDate.Date==DateTime.Now.Date && x.ModuleType==startWorkSendMobileDto.ModuleType);

        if (checkStartWork != null)
        {
            return new SuccessDataResult<StartWorkResponseMobileDto>(null, Messages.SaveItemSuccess);
        }

        var startWork = _mapper.Map<StartWorkLog>(startWorkSendMobileDto);
        var insertResult = await startWorkDal.Add(startWork);

        if (!insertResult)
        {
            return new ErrorDataResult<StartWorkResponseMobileDto>(Messages.SaveItemError);
        }

        return new SuccessDataResult<StartWorkResponseMobileDto>(null, Messages.SaveItemSuccess);
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        return new ErrorDataResult<StartWorkResponseMobileDto>(Messages.AnErrorOccured);
    }
}
```

I try to use tracking query. But it can not solve this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Qus.png)

Comment: There's no EF code in this question. We can't answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to store the posted value. And compare it with next request value, if they are the same, return some error. And the session could expire fast such as 5 seconds.
To initialize session service in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options => {
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);//You can set expire time   
});

app.UseSession();
```

In your controller

```
public async Task<IDataResult<StartWorkResponseMobileDto>> SendStartWork(StartWorkSendMobileDto startWorkSendMobileDto)
{
    var session1=HttpContext.Session.GetString("Session1");  //get the value from session;
    if (session1== startWorkSendMobileDto.xxx)   
        {
           return Problem("Depulicated post");
        }
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Session1", startWorkSendMobileDto.xxx); //note that session can only save string, so pick up some value for storing
    try
    {
        ...
```

By doing this, same requests won't send unless idle for 5 seconds.
If using session have conflict with your project, you may consider using database or redis to store the compare value, also compare with the data create time etc.